# Jquery delay function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an password field and an small icon on right and I want to show the inputted password for 2 sec when user click on the icon.
What I have done is.

```
$("#showpass").click(function(){
   $('#pass').attr('type','text').delay(2000).attr('type','password');
);
```

It does nothing but when I only do `$('#pass').attr('type','text')` it works without any issue.

Comment: If i'm not mistaken, not all browsers support the changing of an input type.

Comment: but many does at least all new ones.

Comment: Ah I see.. IE didn't support it in the past.. but it does now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delay only works with functions that use the jQuery queue such as animations, thus you are getting no delay between setting the type to text and type back to password.

Your particular issue can be solved with `setTimeout()`.

```
$("#showpass").click(function(){
   var pass = $('#pass').attr('type','text');
   setTimeout(function() {
       pass.attr('type','password');
   }, 2000);
);
```

Answer (score 1):

> The .delay() method is best for delaying between queued jQuery
>   effects. Because it is limited—it doesn't, for example, offer a way to
>   cancel the delay—.delay() is not a replacement for JavaScript's native
>   setTimeout  function, which may be more appropriate for certain use
>   cases.

better use it only for animation issues :

https://api.jquery.com/delay/

use setTimeout instead.